# Method throwing Thread was being aborted on more than 100 threads

Tags: c#

I have 500 ids to process. this is my code

```
double task_delay_threshold = 3000;
int threshold = 4;
var lst_of_tasks = new List<Task>();

for (var i = 0; i < ids.Count; i += threshold)
{
    var ids_to_process = ids.Skip(i).Take(threshold).ToList();

    foreach (var c in ids_to_process)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => DoProcess(accessToken, c, userId, programId, guid, fbModel);
        lst_of_tasks.Add(task);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(lst_of_tasks.ToArray());
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(task_delay_threshold));
    lst_of_tasks.RemoveAll(x => x.IsCompleted);
}
```

in do process, I am calling external web api by passing id and then after extracting that data I am inserting data in db

the issue is after processing 100 or sometimes 120 or more, less my this process stops automatically. I have noted logged exception is thread was being aborted

but when I am processing 100 or less it is processing all ids but for more than 100 throwing an exception or sometimes not giving anything just stop

I tried whenall
and waitall both functions

Comment: That is some strange batching -- skip 0, take 4; skip 1, take 4... Shouldn't you skip `i + threshold`?

Comment: @LyoshaKorogoda it is i+=threshold so i will become 4 on second turn instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

There may be some timing issues going on with larger numbers of tasks to process, and I don't quite understand how the loop within loop you've got there is supposed to work.  My inclination would be to simplify (provided you're already referencing Linq):

```
double task_delay_threshold = 3000;
int threshold = 4;
var lst_of_tasks = ids_to_process.Select(p => Task.Run(() => DoProcess(accessToken, p, userId, programId, guid, fbModel)).ToArray();
await Task.WhenAll(lst_of_tasks.ToArray());
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(task_delay_threshold));
```

I would also have a look at [exception handling for task-parallel library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library).

Comment: I have to take delay after some ids processing so after 4 task I am taking delay so in your case it will open all thread

Comment: So, you want 4 different queues, then, each to process sequentially? You don't want this done in parallel, which is what you're trying to do with await?

Comment: Yes I am trying to do 4 task each time.